# Vue.js: Prevent form submit only if condition true

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I am using [VeeValidate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/) for validating a form. However, I want to submit the form without using JS. However, I still want users not to be able to submit, if there are any errors. If I use

```
<form @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">
```

it is disabling the default action completely.

Can you think of any solution to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VeeValidate, but why not try something like this:

```html
<form @submit="validateBeforeSubmit">
```

```js
validateBeforeSubmit(e) {
  if (this.errors.any()) {
    // Prevent the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is only working in Chrome, not in Firefox f.e. Any other solution?

Comment: It works for me in Firefox ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/152/)), can you provide a fiddle for me to test?

Comment: Oh, that works fine. Thank you very much! I was using "this.$validator.validateAll().then" to detect errors, but there is really no need to do it this way.

Comment: almost, I think that you need to add a parameter in your form, called $event so it becomes <form @submit="validateBeforeSubmit($event)"> see vue forum https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/541/how-to-get-info-on-the-element-that-triggers-an-event/6

Answer (score 0):

Try to add () for validateBeforeSubmit like this:

```
<form @submit="validateBeforeSubmit()">
```